# JPQL throws Could not determine data type for searched case statement even when direct SQL query works

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I am trying to update a table by following way:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
        "UPDATE TestCaseExecutionDetailsEntity " +
        " SET status = " +
        " CASE WHEN (runOrder < :runOrder) THEN :completedStatus " +
        "      WHEN (runOrder = :runOrder) THEN :failedStatus " +
        "      WHEN (runOrder > :runOrder) THEN :abortedStatus " +
        " END " +
        " WHERE testExecutionJobId = :jobId")
    .setParameter("jobId", jobId)
    .setParameter("runOrder", runOrder)
    .setParameter("completedStatus", completed.name())
    .setParameter("failedStatus", failed.name())
    .setParameter("abortedStatus", aborted.name())
    .executeUpdate();
```

For value `jobId = 1037` and `runOrder = 2`, it throws error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException:
>   Could not determine data type for searched case statement
>   [update com.pkg.dataaccess.model.TestCaseExecutionDetailsEntity  set status =  CASE WHEN (runOrder < :runOrder) THEN :completedStatus       WHEN (runOrder = :runOrder) THEN :failedStatus       WHEN (runOrder > :runOrder) THEN :abortedStatus  END  WHERE testExecutionJobId = :jobId]

But if I try to run SQL directly, it is working fine:

```
UPDATE TEST_CASE_EXECUTION_DETAILS tcxd
SET tcxd.STATUS =
CASE WHEN (tcxd.RUN_ORDER < 2) THEN 'completed'
WHEN (tcxd.RUN_ORDER = 2) THEN 'failed'
WHEN (tcxd.RUN_ORDER > 2) THEN 'aborted'
END
WHERE TEST_EXECUTION_JOB_ID = 1037;
```

I am clueless on why this is happening. Otherwise, I have to put logic in codebase and that might go messy.

Full Stack Trace -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not determine data type for searched case statement [update com.pkg.dataaccess.model.TestCaseExecutionDetailsEntity tcede  set tcede.status =  CASE WHEN (tcede.runOrder < :runOrder) THEN :completedStatus       WHEN (tcede.runOrder = :runOrder) THEN :failedStatus       WHEN (tcede.runOrder > :runOrder) THEN :abortedStatus  END  WHERE tcede.testExecutionJobId = :jobId]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:294) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy116.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) ~[spring-orm-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy80.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.pkg.dataaccess.repository.TestDataAccessorRepository.updateCaseDetailsForFailedJob(TestRunsDataAccessorRepository.java:542) ~[classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.updateCaseDetailsForFailedJob(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at com.pkg.rest.controllers.EmailController.get(EmailController.java:51) ~[classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81) ~[jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144) ~[jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161) ~[jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160) ~[jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99) ~[jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389) ~[jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102) ~[jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317) [jersey-common-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154) [jersey-server-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228) [jersey-container-servlet-core-2.25.jar:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:509) [catalina.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1104) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1524) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.41]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1480) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.41]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_121]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_121]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.41]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not determine data type for searched case statement [update com.pkg.dataaccess.model.TestCaseExecutionDetailsEntity tcede  set tcede.status =  CASE WHEN (tcede.runOrder < :runOrder) THEN :completedStatus       WHEN (tcede.runOrder = :runOrder) THEN :failedStatus       WHEN (tcede.runOrder > :runOrder) THEN :abortedStatus  END  WHERE tcede.testExecutionJobId = :jobId]
        at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        ... 72 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Could not determine data type for searched case statement
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SearchedCaseNode.getDataType(SearchedCaseNode.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.BinaryLogicOperatorNode.extractDataType(BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.BinaryLogicOperatorNode.initialize(BinaryLogicOperatorNode.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.prepareLogicOperator(HqlSqlWalker.java:1369) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.evaluateAssignment(HqlSqlWalker.java:1270) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.assignment(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1063) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.setClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:763) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.updateStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:379) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1907) ~[hibernate-core-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.1.0.Final.jar:5.1.0.Final]
        ... 72 more
```

Comment: that exception likely has a nested exception. And that query executes SQL. So look at what it is executing ...

Comment: Updated with full stack trace

Comment: FWIW `CASE` needs an `ELSE` to comply with JPQL BNF.

Comment: For each `WHEN`, I have to provide `ELSE` ?

Comment: Yes, when I remove else from my test it gives almost the same error. Did not realize since I automatically used it in my own test...

Comment: For each case it has to have an else before the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with the query below. Simply casting the variables inside the `CASE` statement worked for me:

```
SELECT SUM(
    CASE WHEN type = 'SOME_TYPE' THEN CAST(price AS float) ELSE CAST (-price AS FLOAT) END
)
FROM MyEntity;
```

Comment: After all these months... Thanks. It worked. Although I have already pushed with raw-sql based solution. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if [hibernate](/questions/tagged/hibernate) supports something else but with [jpql](/questions/tagged/jpql) you usually need to set and point to a an ***alias*** of an `entity`.

So try your query with these little changes (so with alias `tcede`):

```
"UPDATE TestCaseExecutionDetailsEntity tcede " +
    " SET tcede.status = " +
    " CASE WHEN (tcede.runOrder < :runOrder) THEN :completedStatus " +
    "      WHEN (tcede.runOrder = :runOrder) THEN :failedStatus " +
    "      WHEN (tcede.runOrder > :runOrder) THEN :abortedStatus " +
    " END " +
    " WHERE tcede.testExecutionJobId = :jobId")
```

Comment: @theGamblerRises This still might not be the fix but I forgot to add alias also to WHEN clauses... Did you happen to add them? See updated answer.

Comment: @theGamblerRises btw: I suppose your hibernate version support at least jpa2, case is avail only starting from that.

Comment: Yes, my hibernate version is `5.1.0.Final`